# Problems binding to AD LDS from an IIS application

Tags: wcf, iis, active-directory

I have a simple WCF Service Application that I want to connect to an active directory for basic authentication.  I can install, configure and add users to my AD LDS instance using my personal credentials (I'm an administrator).  However, IIS can't bind to the instance.  If I restart IIS using my credentials, everything binds just find and the authentication works as expected.

However, I don't want to run IIS with administrator privs.  How do I configure AD LDS so that an app pool in IIS can bind but won't have the kind of elevated privs that can be a security nightmares?

Comment: Have you considered using `service account` and giving that account permissions in AD LDS? You can then run your `AppPool` as that `service account`.

Comment: That solves only half the equation.  How does an Operator/Administrator then add users/groups to the AD/LDS?  Ideally, you'd want a group like 'AD Administrator Group' that has individual (administrator) accounts as well as IUSR, but the AD LDS Wizard won't install if you use a group.

Comment: If you add your service account in `Administrators` role in AD LDS, you will be able to perform `crud` operations and be able to `authenticate` individual users with their `usernames` and `password`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  You are creating a massive security hole.  You want IIS and any other service you expose to the outside world to run with the fewest amount of privs possible.  That way if someone were to find a flaw in IIS (or your web service), the damage they could do is minimized.